# multiple font size in button text

Tags: android, android-button

With this line

```
myButton.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red' size='50dp'>First</font><br/><font color='blue' size='20dp'>Second</font>"));
```

The first line is indeed red, and the second line is blue, but I can't control the font size of either text line, what gives?  How can I do it?

Comment: I've tried same approach and can't set font size either. Also tried with html5 style attribute without success...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try setting the font size of the button to 50dp and using the `<small>` tag for the text you want to make smaller. Of course, this would not be the exact font size you want.

Comment: thanks Chase.  font size should work I'm told, but at least you've given me an alternative